# Type parameter in a method of a Haxe interface

Tags: generics, haxe, type-parameter

I try to create an interface, which has a generic map method, like:

```
interface Observable<U> {
    function map<V>(f:U->V):Observable<V>;
}
```

which gives this error:

```
Class not found : V
```

is there any way to do this without change `V` to `Dynamic`?

Comment: are you sure your case is exactly what you described? Your example works just fine on try.haxe.org: http://try.haxe.org/#FE3aa

Comment: thx, i have to check what is the case, i got the error only when I compile the munit tests